# PyQt5 Quit button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Could you please explain why the quit push button does not work properly in this case:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()       
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               
        qbtn = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.move(50, 50)       
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)   
        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But works if I include the last three lines in a function:

```
def fun():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

fun()
```

I don't understand the mechanics :(

Comment: What do you mean "not work properly"? It works the same to me.

Comment: When I click the button in the first case nothing happens. In the second case, the window will be actually closed

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Windows 7. Am I only one with different behaviour for these two cases? :)

Comment: It's just that code, it's not a summary of your code.

Comment: If I run that code the window doesn't even close. For anyone else who finds this, I had a quick look around and instead of `QCoreApplication.instance().quit`, `self.close` can be used.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem while using linux.  This code comes from a tutorial
on zetcode.com for PyQt5 in the quitButton.py file. Here is the solution that I found works:

Instead of using:

```
qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
```

Replace it with this:

```
qbtn.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

After this, you shouldn't need to call it in a separate function. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this recently. I need a sure exit from within spyder and this always seems a problem with pyqt. I found

- `qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)` will quit and leave window open.
- `qbtn.clicked.connect(self.close)` will close the window but leave the process running.
- `qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)` and
  `qbtn.clicked.connect(self.close)` sequentially will quit and close window.

This is pyqt5 on Python 3.8.8. Hope this is helpful.